# Kendo Mobile - "flat" skin incorrectly displays footer tabstrip tabs on Android 2.3

Tags: android, css, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

When testing on both the Android 2.3 simulator and devices, the tabstrip adds an extra tab that is blank (black background). This occurs when there is more than one tab in the tabstrip. Upon removing the "skin" property of the kendo mobile app initialization, the tabstrip is correct.

Does the new skin have some sort of differing flexbox implementation that could be causing this? Again, this only occurs on Android 2.3.

I am using the Kendo UI Mobile Q2 2013 Release w/ JQuery 1.9.1.

**HTML**:

```
<div data-role="view">
    <footer data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="tabstrip">
        <a href="tab1.html">Tab1</a>
        <a href="tab2.html">Tab2</a>
        <a href="tab3.html">Tab3</a>
    </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
    skin: "flat"
    });
```

**UPDATE**:

Interestingly enough, the problem does NOT occur when using a template to define the footer.